# Piping email to php script

Tags: php, email, permissions, cpanel, whm

I've been searching for an answer for 2 days now and have found so much, but still can't get this to work.

I have a WHM server with a cPanel account.

I have created the following php script under public_html at /home/USERNAME/help-system/parse.php for testing:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
mail('****@davidslack.co.uk', 'Test email', 'Test email to get an email into the script');
?>
```

I have also created a forwarder in cPanel that forwards to:

```
|/home/USERNAME/help-system/parse.php
```

The php script and directory have permissions 0755 (also tried 0777)

Now, when I send an email to the correct address I get a bounce back email like:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  pipe to |/home/USERNAME/help-system/parse.php
    generated by *********@davidslack.co.uk
    local delivery failed

The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ pipe to |/home/USERNAME/help-system/parse.php
       generated by *********@davidslack.co.uk ------

Extension '/home/USERNAME/help-system/parse.php' not present.

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
```

What have I missed? Is there a WHM or cPanel setting I haven't enabled? Have I done something stupid with the above?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I may have found the answer! Edit the php file in the cPanel editor and delete the newline after the hashbang (shebang) then put it in again. This gets rid of the windows new line and adds in the unix new line!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email Piping, looks like it can't understand the windows newline!

So:

1. Create php script
2. Add hashbang to the top of the script
3. Upload
4. Open in cPanel -> File manager -> Code editor
5. Delete the newline after the hashbang and add it back in
6. Save

All working now

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that the difference between a windows new line and a unix new line can destroy a day from someone's life in this way :(