# Email forward to PHP script always bounces

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I am trying to execute a PHP script when an email is received on a managed server, and I only have access through cPanel.

Following [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462991/executing-something-when-the-server-receives-an-email/20463133?noredirect=1) I was able to get the script to work, but it still bounces the content of the email back to the sender.

I tried to read the stdin as suggested by [this post](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/email-forward-php-script-39083.html), but nothing changed. Adding a `$emailtext = mailRead();` does read the stdin, and adding `echo $emailtext;` it writes the email text in the bounced email (so I get the text twice, one from my `echo` and once at the end of the bounced email.)

The bounce is sent by `Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@sti.stidev.com>`, here is the content (in bold italic the parts that I changed):

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> pipe to ***|/path/to/php/script***
>       generated by ***email@address.com***
>
> The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:
>
> ------ pipe to ***|/path/to/php/script***
>          generated by ***email@address.com*** ------
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17 Content-type: text/html
>
> ***here is see any output echo-ed by the script***
>
> ------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
>
> Return-path: ...

How do I get rid of that bounce email?

Comment: Does the script you pipe to have the correct permissions to execute (755) on the server? Also can you share the full dump, perhaps there is a syntax error or the path is incorrect. Without more log details it is difficult to determine where the issue is.

Comment: The script works well. If it creates a text file, the file is created; if it echoes some text, the text appears in the bounce. I tried to end it with `exit(0)`, `exit(1)`, `exit`, `exit("some text")` and without exit call. The text appears in the bounce, the numbers don't.

Comment: does it have the correct permissions? like I said already, without a full dump of the log there isn't much in the posted code that indicates the issue. I had this same issue a few months back and it was strictly permission based. Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757430/piping-email-to-php-script?rq=1 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `-q` at the end of the shebang.

Here are the steps that finally gave me a working script:

1. In cPanel create an email forwarder to a script file
2. Make sure that
   the script file does not contain `/n/l`, but only `/n` (no Windows
   new lines in Linux)
3. Make sure that the script starts with the
   correct shebang: `#!/usr/bin/php -q`
4. Set the script permission to
   executable

Removing the `-q` at the end of the shebang causes the email to bounce back to the sender. Any text echo-ed by the php script is included, and it can be useful for debugging.

Points 2 and 3 made me waste hours. I spent time also trying to read the stdin and trying different exit values: the stdin doesn't need to be read as explained [here](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/email-forward-php-script-39083.html), the script doesn't need to `exit(0)` or any `exit` at all.

Of course this worked for me, and may not work with different configurations. But here is my answer, hoping that it will help someone else.